# Is image of homomorphism is a subgroup?

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $G$ is any group, $N\lhd G$, and $φ\colon G → H$ a homomorphism of $G$ onto $H$, prove that the image, $φ (N)$, of $N$ is a normal subgroup of $H$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to show that $h\cdot\phi(N)=\phi(N)\cdot h$ for all $h\in H$. By surjectivity of $\phi$, we can write $h=\phi(g)$ with $g\in G$. Plug, use that $\phi$ is a homomorphism, then use that $N\lhd G$.

Alternatively: Show that $H\mapsto G/N$, $h\mapsto gN$ where $g$ is such that $\phi(g)=h$, is well-defined, and is a homomorphism with kernel $\phi(N)$.